# PHP date() not returning correct time?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to figure out why my current PHP date() function is not returning the correct time.

As of this moment, my real-life date/time is 2015:10:23 18:49(sec), however for some reason when I run my php code, I get 2015-10-24 00:49:15. For some reason it thinks I'm 6hrs ahead? I'm in Eastern Standard Time by the way, in case it helps.

**PHP**

```
$today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

echo "The date and time right now is " . $today;
```

I'm attempting to code the current date/time into my MySQL database, to log when a member created their account (and later update to log when why last logged in). How do I fix this so it's correct for anyone who uses it?

Comment: http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/php/setting-the-timezone-for-php-in-the-phpini-file

Comment: Check the timezone of your server.... I'm guessing UTC

Comment: What does [`date_default_timezone_get`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php) say?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

include this line on the top of your php code.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Beirut');
```

while instead of asia/beirut, get your country..

check the link to see all supported countries

> http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Comment: Well, this has fixed things on my end, but will it adjust for people who aren't in my timezone?

Comment: You will need to set the location based on their countries.
why don't you prompt them for their country when they go on your website

Comment: Well, my country has multiple time zones (USA). I feel it'd be weird to ask for that, as I don't remember other website asking for that. Is there some way I can get the server to just figure it out on it's own?

Comment: http://www.onlineaspect.com/2007/06/08/auto-detect-a-time-zone-with-javascript/ Use JS For it

Comment: Thank you! I'll look into that!